# why inner style is not working in html progress

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply `linear-gradient` to html progress bar but it's not applying the gradient

```js
var customColor = '#cf014d';

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("progress", { max: "100", value: "80",
  style: { color: "linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #fff)" } }), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `color` cannot be `linear-gradient` - that's only for `background-image`

Comment: Please do not post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just create a "Code Snippet" right here in your question so we can see everything in one place and more easily come up with an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `background:` instead of `color:`

`color` - is for text color

Comment: Thanks. I did try with background but it still doesnt show gradient

Answer (score 0):

Use `background:` for the background color. `color` is for the foreground color.

But, beyond that, progress bars are rendered in a proprietary way by each user agent, one set of styling rules won't work for all browsers. Just setting the style of the element is not enough, the browser renders a progress bar as a series of elements and each part must be styled correctly.

Here' is an example of creating the progress bar with React, but styling it with static CSS for rendering in browsers compliant with the `-webkit-` vendor prefix.

```js
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("progress", { max: "100", value: "80" }), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
                            transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%, 
                            rgba(0,0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
                            rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), 
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #09c, #f44);

    border-radius: 2px; 
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it looks like it still doesnt apply gradient on progress bar

Comment: Thank you @Scott Marcus. Is it possible to pass start color and end color to linear-gradient from javascript to css? i have requirement where user can pass any colors to linear-gradient. Or do you know any other way i could achieve that.

Comment: @jose1221 You would just set the style via JavaScript, rather than hard-code it as I've shown. The point is that setting up just one style is not enough to style a progress bar.

Comment: Can you please give me an example or point me to some link on how to set the style via javascript? sorry i am learning javascript

Comment: @jose1221 https://www.google.com/search?q=set+css+via+javascript&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS761US761&oq=set+css+via+&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

> Background property will style the "background" part - not the value.

Here is a nice article for styling the progress bar. 
https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/